# modify ggplot axis labels to include greek characters and subscripts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to modify the y-axis labels of my ggplot to include both greek letters and subscripts, but my code is not working.

Example:

```
set.seed(42)
data.frame(x = rnorm(300, 50, 5),
           g = sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), 300, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = g)) +
  geom_violin() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = labeller(c(B1 = expression("\u0392"[1]),
                                       B2 = expression("\u0392"[2]),
                                       B3 = expression("\u0392"[3]))))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ".label", value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3
```

Comment: Don't use `labeller()` here. If you remove that, it works just fine. You generally only need to use `labeller()` and the various `label_*()` functions for facets, not for scales.

Comment: @Axeman, works perfectly. do you want to write up an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your desired output is. I googled this unicode and only found it to be a B, so I just pasted 1-2-3 to that unicode. Did you try to get different types of u0392 (like version 1,2,3, if such exists)? Hope its helpful

```
labs <- paste0(expression("\u0392"),"<sub>",1:3,"</sub>")
set.seed(42)
data.frame(x = rnorm(300, 50, 5),
           g = sample(c("B1", "B2", "B3"), 300, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = g)) +
  geom_violin() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = labs)+
  theme(axis.text = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: What happened to subscript? and `\u0392` is capital beta.

Comment: Those are not subscripts though, you need `[1]`, not `1` to produce a subscript.

Comment: would that be appropriate? labs <- paste0(expression("\u0392"),"<sub>",1:3,"</sub>") ?
then adding  + theme(axis.text = ggtext::element_markdown())